# General .htaccess rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that is hosted via Pagoda Box. I have a question pertaining to writing the .htacess file to force the www portion of the domain name. I'm attempting to have the domain force the www and include it.

The domain name is currently not using the www portion even though the .htaccess file appears to be forcing it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.gopagoda.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wwww.domain.gopagoda.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301    /copy_index.html    http://www.domain.com
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

I'm a novice to .htaccess file editing and have looked through many tutorials but I don't see any that use this syntax like above. The four ws (wwww)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Best,
Morgan

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! You rock! I see my permalink settings are not using the www. Do I change the permalink settings in Wordpress Dashbaord first then edit the .htacesss file or make the edits to the .htaccess file then change the settings in Wordpress Dashboard? I'm hoping to not have any downtime on the site. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Check your WP permalink settings to make sure your website and blog addresses both have `www` in it.**

Then change your rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wwww\.)?domain\.gopagoda\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^copy_index\.html$ / [R=301,L,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```